# PostGIS: Reduce precision in Linestring

Tags: postgis

Is there any way to reduce precision in Linestring coordinates to specified decimal point? For example:

LINESTRING (16.418792399944802 54.24801559999939, 16.4176588 54.248003)

becomes

LINESTRING (16.4187924 54.2480156, 16.4176588 54.248003)

Comment: Have you done a search query for that question and found St_ReducePrecision(geom, tolerance)  ?

Comment: @Kasper Yes. I've also tried this function on data, but it did not get me expected results.

Comment: To get an answer or a solution, you should mention everything you tried in your question

Comment: Does the example query from the documentation https://postgis.net/docs/en/ST_ReducePrecision.html `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_ReducePrecision('POINT(1.412 19.323)', 0.1));` return the expected result for you?